# Upgrading from the command line?

Tags: command-line, upgrade, release-management

I would like to know how to upgrade from my current version of Ubuntu to the next stable from the Command line interface?

Comment: The other answers doesn't address this question.

Comment: Well, they do, but command line is only mentioned as "Run do-release-upgrade in a terminal", as it's that simple, after general steps ("take backups").

Comment: What worked for me is `/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release -d` and then `do-release-upgrade -d` works for me

Comment: For Ubuntu 20.04+, I had to do `sudo apt-get update` + `sudo apt-get upgrade -y` + 
`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and finally `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You'll first need to make sure update-manager-core is present (it may already be installed):

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
```

Next, run:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

You may need to check `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` and change the line:

```
Prompt=lts
```

to:

```
Prompt=normal
```

for the release to show up.

- [Upgrade Documentation](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/upgrade)
- [Upgrade Notes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes)

Comment: I have Ubuntu 17.10 installed. Apparently the `update-manager-core` package has been added to the core packages since the answer was given, as trying to install it yields the output `update-manager-core is already the newest version (1:17.10.13).`, and the command `do-release-upgrade` is available. However, giving this command on the command line produces the output `No new release found.`, even though release 18.04 was released last week. (I do have the line `Prompt=normal` in file `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`.)

Comment: @TeemuLeisti the `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` documentation says ```normal - Check to see if a new release is available.  If more than one new
         release is found, the release upgrader will attempt to upgrade to
         the supported release that immediately succeeds the
         currently-running release.```

Comment: So it seems that setting `Prompt=normal` is NOT enough to update to the latest version.  This will only update you to the second-to-latest version

Comment: I found running `/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release -d` and then `do-release-upgrade -d` works for me

Answer (score 13):

If you run the command `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` through SSH then use a GNU Screen, because the upgrade process will turn off SSH -> close the default port and open a new one (it will inform you of this new port), so:

```
$ ssh USER@HOST

$ screen -S upgrade
$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

open a new terminal on client computer:

```
$ ssh -p PORT USER@HOST

$ screen -d
$ screen -r upgrade
```

Comment: sudo do-release-upgrade -d is for devel release If you want to do LTS to the next one just use: sudo do-release-upgrade without the "-d" switch

Comment: As of Ubuntu 14.04 (and possibly ealier), `do-release-upgrade` now automatically creates a `screen` for you to make it easier to recover a failed upgrade. It also starts a secondary ssh server for the same reason. So this advice is no longer necessary.

Comment: I have been trying for months to upgrade from Mate 16.04 to 18.04 but have been completely blocked by Blue Ray software & hardware upgrade errors. The Java component wouldn't install, so I did so from terminal. Now a base portion of the program which the others are dependencies of. It won't upgrade stating a major error. Attempting to remove it also removes the Mate desktop and all of it's dependencies. What must I do? Remove it & Mate then update to 18.04 & reinstall Mate from only terminal?

Answer (score 5):

You can do

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

for command line updating

(This is actually the same as for [Ubuntu Server](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/upgrade))