# Does dist-upgrade require PPA software to be uninstalled first?

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, upgrade, ppa, dependencies

I'm still running Ubuntu 10.04 with quite a few PPAs. Amongst the PPAs there is [Guiodic (Guido Iodice) Lucid quasi-rolling :)](https://launchpad.net/~guido-iodice/+archive/guiodiclucid) PPA which brings most recent versions of many programs to my desktop.

My steps:

1. sudo update-manager -d
2. click on upgrade on the appearing window
3. wait for the magic to happen: prepare to upgrade and setting new software channels
4. during 'calculating the changes' I will get the following error message in the panel

   An error occurred, please run Package Manager form the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. 
   The error message was: ' Error: Marking the upgrade (E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolver generated breaks, this may be caused by help packages.)'This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies

When I check Synaptic/apt-get I can't find any errors or hint toward broken packages

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/di9CR.png]

Could this error be because of many PPA versions being newer than 10.04 original versions?

Comment: Could you post the error message you get from running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`?

Comment: I'm sorry that I did not provide sufficient details in the first place. I hope that now the issue is more clear.

Comment: drop the -d, just try `update-manager`

Comment: same error message without the -d

Comment: It seems the direct answer to my question is NO. Should I ask another question regarding the error message?

Comment: @DoR the only error I get is shown in the image above: WARNING: Failed to read mirror file

Comment: @seb I am starting to think that this is a bug/problem with update-manager.

Comment: @Jorge found something at [http://list.debian.org](http://lists.debian.org/deity/2002/04/msg00095.html) and [http://debianforum.de](http://debianforum.de/forum/viewtopic.php?f=32&p=766249) and will have a look at the output of `apt-get upgrade -f`

Comment: @seb Excellent! Do keep updating your question with the information, perhaps that output will help solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the direct answer to my question is NO. see above comments.

Answer (score 2):

As hhlp pointed out the update-manager will comment out PPAs before it upgrades you to 10.10.

There are also command line instructions here which talk about `do-release-upgrade`, which is the supported method of upgrading via CLI:

- [Upgrading from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5763/upgrading-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 1):

you have Ubuntu already installed 10.04 and you want to update your version to version 10.10, then click <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run "update-manager", will open a new window.

Click the Update button and start the download and update packages, depending on the state of the network can take a few hours.

this process will comment all your PPA before updated.....

- [Official documentation](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/upgrade) on upgrading

Comment: I'm sorry guys that I did not provide sufficient details in the first place, see above.