# How do I upgrade from 10.04 to 10.10 in one command by using the terminal?

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, upgrade, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upgrading from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5763/upgrading-from-the-command-line)

Hi,

I dont want to use the update manager I just want to type one command in a terminal do you understand?
I am at 10.04 and want to upgrade to 10.10 (and on the 29 of april 11.04) in a terminal, can it be done?

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
[sudo] password for alvar: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
alvar@alvars-laptop:~$
```

Comment: With `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` it should work.

Comment: IT DIDN'T! GRRR...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this:

[Upgrading from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5763/upgrading-from-the-command-line/5766#5766)

Comment: I think that link makes it pretty clear. Cheers for posting that up.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Still same problem nothing happened (newest version were installed).

Comment: @Alvar - sorry, I left off `update-manager-core` which is apparently required. I'm sure I just did the one-liner in that past and it worked. Perhaps the problem is that you're on an LTS version. Not sure.

Comment: From [here](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/09/28/upgrade-ubuntu-from-10-04-to-10-10/) --> Now we need to make a simple edit to the /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades. This file determines the default behavior for the release upgrader. The line you need to change is at the bottom of this file. Change it from:

`Prompt=lts`

to

`Prompt=normal`  Then: `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`