# How can I upgrade ubuntu 10.04 to 11.04?

Tags: upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I skip over releases?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases)

What should I do for this? I know, that upgrade goes step by step, but HOW? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you would need to upgrade to 10.10 then 11.04. You can't just skip a release. but you can upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04 (LTS to LTS).

there are a lot of questions on this point at the site, here's some.

- [Upgrading from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/a/5766/10698)
- [How do I upgrade straight from a very old release to the latest one?](https://askubuntu.com/a/34435/10698)

Answer (score 1):

With  this simple command :

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -p
```