# Failing to upgrade Ubuntu or run updates from the command line, apt-get giving 404s

Tags: command-line, apt, upgrade, updates, ssh

I would like to upgrade my Ubuntu 11.04 from the command line (this is a remote machine I can only SSH into). I am following [these directions](https://askubuntu.com/a/5766). I am getting 404's from many commands I am trying to run such as:

- `sudo apt-get install update-manager-core`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install libkrb5-dev`

**What can I do to apt-get install these things without 404s from the command line?** I can only use the command line.

Here is an example of the 404.

```
$ sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
[sudo] password for melissa:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  update-manager-core
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 95 not upgraded.
Need to get 165 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,294 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  update-manager-core
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates/main update-manager-core amd64 1:0.150.5.4
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-security/main update-manager-core amd64 1:0.150.5.4
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/update-manager/update-manager-core_0.150.5.4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `apt-get update` first. Without that, it can try downloading files which are no longer current.

Also - as natty is no longer current version - update `/etc/apt/sources.list` with new repo location, it should be in `old-releases.ubuntu.com`, instead of `archive.ubuntu.com`. (and run `apt-get update` after that).

See here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2150989 for details.