# Upgrading from 10.04 to 16.04

Tags: command-line, upgrade

I have Ubuntu 10.04 and I want to install 16.04.

I have created a USB using a lot of programs, even the one came with the distro; when I try to install 16.04 the monitor shows all it is supposed to show, but without brightness like it is turned off.

Only with a specific boot and a lot of imagination to confuse the system he authorizes me to install Ubuntu.

My question is:

Is it possible to install 16.04 or another version from the desktop from the terminal or something?

Or this can only be done from outside?

```
mia@mia-laptop:~$ lspci -k

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 09)
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel
    Kernel modules: intel-agp

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1a.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1a.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.3 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
    Kernel modules: iTCO_wdt

00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation ICH9M/M-E 2 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
    Kernel modules: i2c-i801

00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation ICH9M/M-E 2 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix

04:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k

05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5784M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 10)
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
    Kernel modules: tg3
```

Comment: Upgrading via the terminal probably won't help if you can't even boot the stock 16.04. I'm not an expert of the field, but please add the output of `lspci -k` to your question, it could help others in identyfing the problem.

Comment: sorry I don't know what it means

Comment: `lspci -k` is a command to run in terminal which will show the hardware. The problems you are encountering are likely due to your hardware, and knowing what hardware you have will help a lot for finding a solution to your problem (n.b. upgrading using a fresh install is probably the best method with such a old release). If you have tried 16.04 only that is probably the issue as it is not stable yet so bugs will still exist

Comment: is that what you meant ?

Answer (score 2):

As an exercise, can you try install ubuntu 14.04 first? Anyway, AFAIK it is not possible to upgrade directly to 14.04 or 16.04 directly, no matters what. You have to jump want step at a time, first to 12.04, 14.04 and then 16.04.

Regarding 16.04, if you do not have much experience with Linux and Ubuntu, I would suggest not to try it. It is still not official and may have bugs here and there. You will not know what the problems really are.

Last but not least, I did not have succeed with any of the bootable USB creator recommended by Canonical. The one I find every easy to use is [Yumi](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator) (the Windows version). I haven't tried the Linux version http://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/YUMI/ubuntu/yumi_0.0.1-1_all.deb

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Ubuntu 16 via a key bottable: it is a bad idea, it is highly instable for the moment!
Ubuntu 14 is the most stable for me, or you may try the 15.

For answer to your question: for upgrading your version by terminal, you can, see related post:
[Upgrading from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5763/upgrading-from-the-command-line)

But i offen reinstall ubuntu via USB key, it seems safer to me...

Comment: i don't mind fresh start I want know is upgrade from 10.04 to ne newest version possible, via terminal or a program, because the bios don't let me do otherwise