# Upgrade Ubuntu from 18.10 to 19.04

Tags: upgrade

Software updater tells me I can do the upgrade, when I do it, at stage "installing upgrades", I get:

```
Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nmap/nmap-common_7.70+dfsg1-6_all.deb 403  Forbidden [IP: 194.158.119.186 80]
```

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

It stays there is nothing to upgrade

I also tried solution from [this post](https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=2015019), but it didnt work.

What can I do ?

Comment: Have you tried it again?   I can download that file without issue.

Comment: did you do `sudo do-release-upgrade` ?

Comment: have you tried to download from an alternative server?

Comment: Have you read this question?
https://askubuntu.com/questions/5763/upgrading-from-the-command-line

Comment: We are going to be suggesting things here that we think will work.  One thing that I can think of is that since `nmap` is not actually installed by default, try removing it first by doing `sudo apt remove nmap` then try your upgrade again.

Comment: @Juliatzin - you do realize `sudo apt dist-upgrade` is not the correct way to release-upgrade from 18.10 to 19.04.  I assume you are trying to fully-upgrade your system prior to performing the release-upgrade step.

Comment: @guiverc yep, I have the same issue with do-release-upgrade. I'm trying to remove nmpa as Terrance suggested

Comment: remove nmap seems to be working. I'll confirm when it s done :)

Comment: @Terrance it worked. Thanks ! please put it as answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nmap` is actually and application that is not installed by default, so it should be safe to remove it before upgrading your distro of Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt remove nmap
```

After you run through the upgrade you should be able to reinstall `nmap` later by running

```
sudo apt install nmap
```

Hope this helps!